# Save Image source to database using .net core 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to create a shop where I have a product that has an array of photos, and I want to save these images or their source (where the picture itself is located in the project folder) into the database.

I was thinking about creating a separate entity for the picture and a one-to-many relationship between the picture and the product.

This is my code -  model class:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ImageSrc { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsDisable { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Role.Admin)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct([FromForm] ProductDTO dTO)
{
    var currentUser = (User)HttpContext.Items["User"];

    if (currentUser.Role != Role.Admin)
        return  StatusCode(403, new { message = "Forbidden" });

    dTO.ImageName = await SaveImage(dTO.Image);
    var product = service.CreateProduct(dTO);

    return Created("createproduct", product);
}

[NonAction]
public async Task<string> SaveImage(IFormFile imageFile)
{
    string imageName = new String(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(' ', '-');
    imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(imageFile.FileName);
    var imagePath = Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", imageName);

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }

    return imageName;
}
```

Repository

```
public Product CreateProduct(Product product)
{
    var produc = new Product
        {
            ProductName = product.ProductName,
            Description = product.Description,
            UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice,
            ImageName=product.ImageName
        };

    foreach (var item in product.Categories)
    {
        var category = context.Categories
                              .Where(w => w.Id == item.Id)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

        produc.Categories.Add(category);
    }

    context.Products.Add(produc);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return new Product
        {
            Id = produc.Id,
            ProductName = produc.ProductName,
            Description = produc.Description,
            UnitPrice = produc.UnitPrice,
            Categories = produc.Categories,
            ImageName=produc.ImageName
        };
}
```

Service

```
public Product CreateProduct(ProductDTO dTO)
{
    var product = new Product
        {
            Description = dTO.Description,
            ProductName = dTO.Name,
            UnitPrice = dTO.UnitPrice,
            Categories = dTO.Categories,
            ImageName=dTO.ImageName,
        };

    var pro = repos.CreateProduct(product);

    return pro;
}
```

how can I save a source to a picture in the database?

Comment: `i want to save this images or their source(where the picture itself is located in the project folder) to database.` <-- if you ask 100 experts, 99 of them will say you store the _location_ in the database, not the image itself. The 100th will say "it depends" and it will be something like "if you plan to have 10 images or less..."

Comment: ok how can i save an array of images locations?)

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support arrays. Ideally you'd store them relationally, by passing in the set of image paths via a table-valued parameter, and storing each path in its own row relating to the parent. But what most people do, since it's easy I guess, is store a comma-separated list of strings in a single column.